# Tulip Regeneration

Tags: tulips

Happy Mother's Day. I suspect a Mother somewhere is enjoying my Tulips.

Overnight, someone clipped and made off with my bloomed tulips.

Q: will they bloom again this year?

It's my first year with this garden. I'm in US Zone 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry to say no, you will get  no more flowers this year. If the leaves are still present, feed the bulbs with a general fertilizer, because this is the time when they are storing nutrients and creating the flower for next year within the bulb. Once the leaves are no longer green, stop feeding, they can only make use of nutrients whilst the leaves are still functioning. Note though, that tulips are variable - many varieties don't reappear the following year, or don't produce flowers.